# How do I check write speeds to a container? AZure DLS Gen 2

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm doing some work to test the write speeds of different output serializations (Avro, Parquet etc) for a streaming use case. I can see the size of the files, but how can I check other metrics like speed/latency and other interesting comparative factors? I am also using Eventhubs and Stream Analytics, if these can offer a solution too.

Comment: Check - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-verify-metrics, similarly for datalake storage as well you can go to your Azure Portal, you can navigate to the container and select the "Metrics" tab. This will show you various metrics, including the average ingress and egress rates, which can give you an idea of the write speeds.

Comment: This is perfect thank you, exactly the resource I was looking for - I would mark as answered but not sure how with a comment

Comment: Glad to hear it. I will post the same as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking write speeds on Azure DLS Gen 2, you can go to your Azure Portal, under your storage account, navigate to the "Metrics" tab. This will show you various metrics, including the average ingress and egress rates, which can give you an idea of the write speeds. You can also customize what you want to see based on the various Metric namespace.
[image]

Reference document-
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-verify-metrics)